# failed to avoid “[: too many arguments”

Tags: bash, shell, double-quotes

**I know** that `MyVar="a b" ; [ $MyVar = "a b" ]` will signal an error because the resultant expansion is `[ a b = "a b" ]`.

I tried to avoid that case:

```bash
$ MyVar="\"a b\""
$ [ $MyVar = "a b" ]
-bash: [: too many arguments
```

Why did I fail?  *Didn't it expand to `[ "a b" = "a b" ]`?*

---

**I know** there is a `[[ ... ]]` form; **I know** I can write `"$MyVar"`.

I am asking *why is my approach ineffective*.

Comment: try this: MyVar="a b" ; [ "$MyVar" == "a b" ] && echo ok

tl;tr; without "" expression evaluates to [ a b == "a b" ]

Comment: @Vicctor: `==` is not allowed in `POSIX` mode, see my answer

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes *before* expanding variables, so putting quotes and/or escapes in variables doesn't work -- by the time they're part of the command, it's too late for them to do anything useful. See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

Comment: enable debug mode (`set -xv`) and run your code again to see what `bash` is seeing

Comment: Quotes *in* a parameter are data; quotes *surrounding* a parameter expansion are syntax.

Comment: @chepner: Your comment is incisive, how about making it an answer? I’ll upvote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is my approach ineffective.

That's because `$MyVar` without quotes will be split into
`"a` and `b"` (two strings) and the `==` operator only works with *one* argument on the left hand side and one argument on the right hand side.

Note that parameter expansion is a one-pass thing. It expands the variable `$MyVar` into `"a` and `b"` and does then not reevaluate the result. The order in which the expansions occur is listed in [Shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html):

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion.

Comment: So `$MyVar` is split into `"a` and `b"`, and *then* they are inserted into the `test` form?

Comment: @shynur Exactly

Comment: It would be better if you give *short precise citations/references* and links to corresponding them.  Upvote in advance.

Comment: @shynur The full chapter on parameter expansion is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). I'm not sure if it contains exactly what you need but it contains a lot.

Comment: I mean, extract the key passages. This saves time for anyone who encounters this problem. It's not very important, so, of course, you can refuse. I'm just suggesting. :-)

Comment: @shynur I added a better entry into the documentation at least :)

Answer (score 1):

##### It's because you encounter shell [*word splitting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html): you missed to "quote" the variable.

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Better use this form in `bash`, no need to quote:

```
MyVar="a b" ; [[ $MyVar == "a b" ]]
```

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, I recommend `[[`

---

If you need to write `POSIX` code, you need quotes:

```
MyVar="a b" ; [ "$MyVar" = "a b" ] && echo ok
```

Note the use of **single** `=` operator mandatory for `POSIX` shell.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: "*Note the use of **single** `=` operator mandatory for `POSIX` shell.*" -- Thanks, have upvoted. I will edit my question to use `=`.

Comment: @shynur `==` or `=` doesn't matter here (since it's bash) so why change the question?

Comment: It depends how you call the script. If you use `sh script`, you will encounter error: `unexpected operator`

Comment: @GillesQuénot Sure, but then it wouldn't be a [tag:bash] question :-) I also prefer putting shebangs in my scripts to not just get any random interpreter.

Comment: Do not underestimate how many bash beginner users run bash scripts with `sh`. It's a common pitfall.